# vs code, работа git во встроенном терминале

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

После очередного обновления VS code под Linux работа git в терминале изменилась. Раньше при вводе `git pull/git push` в самом терминале выводился диалог аля введите имя пользователя и пароль. Сейчас появляется поле для ввода вне встроенного терминала вверху редактора. Как вернуть старый режим работы? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не проще ли настроить ssh и вообще не вводить никаких логинов/паролей?

Comment: @AlexeyTen смысл понятен, спасибо, но меня интересует именно указанный порядок действий - ввод логина и пароля или только пароля

Answer (score 3):

Я изучил подробнее настройки VS code по запросу 'git' и нашел как исправить ситуацию: нужно убрать галочку напротив `Git: Terminal Authentication`, как показано на рисунке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]